# Getting the Compile Error: For without Next when running a VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not sure how to wrap a VBA function as I am getting the error "Compile error: For without Next"
Here is my code

```
Sub RenameHeadersZoomInfo()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim LastCol As Long
    LastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xIToLeft).Column
    
    For Each rng In ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, LastCol))
    
        Select Case rng.Value
            Case "Company Name"
                rng.Value = "Name"
            Case "Country"
                rng.Value = "BillingCountry"
            Case "City"
                rng.Value = "BillingCity"
            Case "State"
                rng.Value = "BillingState"
            Case "LinkedIn Company Profile URL"
                rng.Value = "LinkedinCompanyPage__c"
            Case "Owner"
                rng.Value = "Owner.Id"
            Case "Primary Sub-Industry"
                rng.Value = "LinkedinIndustry__c"
            Case "Company HQ Phone"
                rng.Value = "Phone"
            Case "NAICS Code 1"
                rng.Value = "NAICSCode_1__c"
            Case "NAICS Code 2"
                rng.Value = "NAICSCode_2__c"
            Case "Show"
                rng.Value = "Description"
                
        End Select
                
End Sub
```

I edited this VBA code with the help of ChatGPT...

Running it, I had a first error telling me I needed to have an End Select.
So I added the `End Select` at the end of the Select Case function.

Then running the code I get the new error "For without Next".
I tried adding a Next `Cell line` after the `End Select` but its not working.

Comment: Add just a `Next`. Or if you want, `Next rng`.

Comment: Start with the explicit `For Each rng In ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, LastCol)).Cells` and close with `Next rng`. Maybe `cell` (instead of `rng`) would be a more appropriate variable name.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement

Comment: Thanks. I have added `Next Rng` after the `End Select` and it works.